# Show only two year digits

Tags: macros

How can I insert two digit year string?

I know that the command `\the\year` inserts four digit year string. I tried using `\twodigit\year`, but it also returns four digits.

I guess I need some kind of macro, but I don't know how to write one. I tried like this:

```
\newcommand{\shortyear}[4]{
\def\@shortyear{#3#4}}

\shortyear[\the\year]  % Empty string
```

But it returns empty string. The idea was to pass four digits as argument and return only the last two.

Comment: `\twodigit` is used to guarantee that a number is shown with *at least* two digits, not *at most* ;-)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Of course, it is incumbent on the user to make sure the argument is/produces 4 digits.

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\shortyear#1{\expandafter\shortyearhelper#1}
\def\shortyearhelper#1#2#3#4{#3#4}
\begin{document}
\shortyear{\the\year}\par
\shortyear{2036}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How could I export ```\shortyear``` and ```\shortyearhelper``` definitions to my ```style.sty``` file? I tried simply copying the commands, but the behaviour changes.

Comment: @niekas  Copying should suffice, unless you have defined `\shortyear` elsewhere in your code, using an alternate definition.

Comment: Yes, you are right! Thank you very much once again!

Comment: @niekas If you need it to handle dates less than 1000 or greater than 9999, that can be done, but of course takes more code.

Answer (score 11):

A simpler solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\short[1]{\expandafter\@gobbletwo\number\numexpr#1\relax}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\short{\year}

\short{2014}     

\end{document}
```

[image]

In case of numeric argument, you're better using use a four digit number.

Comment: I think, that the second ```\makeatletter``` should be replaced by ```\makeatother```, though I don't know what these commands do ;) Simply recognized the command pattern.

Comment: @niekas Yes, it should.

Comment: Your solution seems to be simple. But it could be more simple (without using eTeX and without catcode manipulation) if you say: `\def\short#1{\csname @gobbletwo\expandafter\endcsname\number#1\relax}`

Comment: @wipet The `\relax` wouldn't make it fully expandable. I see no catcode manipulation in my answer, just access to “private” macros.

Comment: The `\relax` was my mistake. It isn't needed. So: `\def\short#1{\csname @gobbletwo\expandafter\endcsname\number#1}`.

Answer (score 6):

A version using the `\MODULO` command from the `calculator` package. It will not work for too large numbers, however (and too short ones ;-))

*Note*: The calculator package uses length registers internally, it's restricted to values from 0 to 16383, so don't use this code for years beyond 16383 ;-)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{calculator}%

\usepackage{datetime}%

\newcommand{\shortyear}[1]{%
  \gdef\ModuloResult{}%
  \MODULO{\twodigit{#1}}{100}{\ModuloResult}%
  \twodigit{\ModuloResult}%
}

\begin{document}
\shortyear{\year}%

\shortyear{1900}%
\end{document}%
```

[image]

## Improved version -- showing the two digits representation of numbers from 1 to 16383

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{calculator}%

\usepackage{datetime}%
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{forloop}%

\newcommand{\shortyear}[1]{%
  \gdef\ModuloResult{}%
  \MODULO{\twodigit{#1}}{100}{\ModuloResult}%
  \twodigit{\ModuloResult}%
}

\newcounter{loopcounter}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{ll}
  Year & Short year \tabularnewline
\endfirsthead
\forloop{loopcounter}{1}{\number\value{loopcounter} < 16384}{%
  \theloopcounter & \shortyear{\value{loopcounter}} \tabularnewline
}%
\end{longtable}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can also `xstring` for this quite easily:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xstring}
\newcommand*{\shortyear}[1]{\StrRight{0000\number\numexpr#1}{2}\relax}

\begin{document}

\shortyear{2011}
\shortyear{5}

\shortyear{\year}

\end{document}
```

The final `\relax` is there to guarantee the expect spacing after the macro.

Answer (score 6):

I give another solution to this collection of answers. No packages are needed, but eTeX primitives are used.

```
\def\short#1{\ifnum\shortA{#1}<10 0\fi \number\shortA{#1}}
\def\shortA#1{\numexpr #1-((#1-50)/100)*100\relax}

\short\year;  \short{9};  \short{1849});  \short{1989};  \short{123456}. 
%        14;         09;            49;             89;              56.
```

Answer (score 4):

**Simple answer**: With `xtrings` is as simple as `\StrGobbleLeft{\the\year}{2}`.

**Not so simple answer**: In the example below, the `\sy` ("short year") macro *as is*  extract the two digits from the actual default year (i.e, `14`) or from an  optional argument (e.g.  `\sy[1939]`).

This argument also change `\the\year` for later use (e.g. in `\today` to obtain `October 9,1939`)., but if you do not like that feature is quite obvious how remove it.

Finally, as I cannot imagine the benefit of using a two digit format for dates outside the XX or XXI century in real life, the argument only work with 4 digits in order to detect typing mistakes (otherwise print a warning box) with the help of the `xifthen` package. If you do not like this feature either, go to the simple answer.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring,xifthen}
\newcommand{\sy}[1][]{
\StrLen{#1}[\yearlength]%
\ifthenelse{\yearlength = 4}% Only 4 character allowed 
{\year#1\relax\StrGobbleLeft{#1}{2}}%
{\ifthenelse{\yearlength = 0} % What by default 
{\StrGobbleLeft{\the\year}{2}}%
{\fbox{\bfseries\ttfamily OOPS! typed #1}}}}%


\begin{document}
Really today is \today.\par
% Correct use with default year
World War III will start after  \sy\ (... the year \the\year, obviously).\par
% Mistyped date that go to Roman times, so year is not changed.  
World War II started in the \sy[193]\ (... still stuck in \the\year).\par
% Correct use with fixed year   
World War I started in \sy[1914]\ (we mean now \the\year !).\par
Now \verb|\the\year| is still  \the\year, and \verb|\today| is \today.\par
% Mistyped date that go to Star Trek era, so year is not changed.  
Franco-Prussian war started in \sy[18870].\par 
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]