# Different bibliography style

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, hyperref, back-referencing

I am using **References** after each chapter to print cited papers in that chapter, as well as a **Complete Bibliography** at the end. Now, I want a customized version of bibliography at the end of the chapter, while the complete bibliography will have the default setting.

Consider the following MWE (copied from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/36244/38244)):

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[defernums=true, hyperref, backref, refsegment=chapter]{biblatex}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\defbibheading{references}[References]{% 
    \section*{#1}% 
    \markboth{#1}{#1}%
}

\defbibheading{bibliography}[Complete Bibliography]{% 
    \chapter*{#1}%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}
    \markboth{#1}{#1}%
}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @misc{A01,
        author = {Author, A. and Duthor, D.},
        year = {2001},
        title = {Alpha},
        shortdesc = {Conference1}
    }
    @misc{B02,
        author = {Buthor, B. and Euther, E. and Futher F.},
        year = {2002},
        title = {Bravo},
        shortdesc = {Journal2}
    }
    @misc{C03,
        author = {Cuthor, C.},
        year = {2003},
        title = {Charlie},
        shortdesc = {Workshop}
    }
\end{filecontents}

\bibliography{\jobname}


\begin{document}
    \chapter{First Chapter}
    Some more text \autocite{A01,B02}.
    \printbibliography[heading=references,segment=\therefsegment]
    %% This will have differnet format than Complete Bibliography
    %% [#] Lastname1, Lastname2, ...: ShortDescription'yy
    %%% [1] Author, Duthor: Conference1'01
    %%% [2] Buthor, Euther, Futher: Journal2'02
    \chapter{Second Chapter}
    Some text \autocite{A01,C03}.
    \printbibliography[heading=references,segment=\therefsegment]


    \printbibliography[heading=bibliography]

\end{document}
```

I want the **References** will have the format:

> Lastname1, Lastname2, ..., LastnameN: ShortDescription'YY

`Lastname1` to `LastnameN` are last names for `N` authors; `ShortDescription` is a keyword given in the bibentry by `shortdesc`; followed by upper comma `'`; `YY` is the last two digits of the year and no `\backref`. For example, after Chapter 1, we'll have the following **References**:

> [1 ] Author, Duthor: Conference1'01
>
> [2] Buthor, Euther, Futher: Journal2'02

### Update

I just noticed the hyperlink from the citations goes to the **References**. Can this be changed such that it points to the **Main Bibliography** item?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For `shortdesc` we need to define a new datamodel (`.dbx` file). Since all entry types should look the same in the chapter references we used `\printbiblist` so that we can use one driver for all entries. In `\defbibenvironment{chapterref}` we disable the hyperlink anchor so that the link goes to the main bibliography.

The code for the two-digit year is from [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/52421/35864) answer of [Audrey](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4483/audrey)'s. See also [Two-digit year in bib entry for articles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/266069/35864) and [Show only two year digits](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/205180/35864). Note that this requires you to always give four-digit years.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{chapterref.dbx}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=literal]{
  shortdesc,
}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields{shortdesc}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[backref, refsegment=chapter, datamodel=chapterref]{biblatex}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author    = {Author, A. and Duthor, D.},
  year      = {2001},
  title     = {Alpha},
  shortdesc = {Conference1},
}
@misc{B02,
  author    = {Buthor, B. and Euther, E. and Futher F.},
  year      = {2002},
  title     = {Bravo},
  shortdesc = {Journal2},
}
@misc{C03,
  author    = {Cuthor, C.},
  year      = {2003},
  title     = {Charlie},
  shortdesc = {Workshop},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\makeatletter
\defbibenvironment{chapterref}
  {\list
     {\printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
      \printfield{labelprefix}%
      \printfield{labelnumber}}}
     {\let\blx@anchor\relax
      \setlength{\labelwidth}{\labelnumberwidth}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}%
      \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{\hss##1}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}
\makeatother

\DeclareFieldFormat{shortyear}{\mkbibshortyear#1}
\def\mkbibshortyear#1#2#3#4{#3#4}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{chapterref}{%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\multinamedelim}%
  \DeclareNameAlias{author}{labelname}%
  \DeclareNameAlias{editor}{labelname}%
  \DeclareNameAlias{translator}{labelname}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor+others/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{shortdesc}%
  \setunit{'}%
  \printfield[shortyear]{year}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\defbibheading{chapterref}[References]{% 
  \section*{#1}% 
  \markboth{#1}{#1}%
}

\defbibheading{bibliography}[Complete Bibliography]{% 
  \chapter*{#1}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
  \markboth{#1}{#1}%
}

\begin{document}
  \chapter{First Chapter}
  Some more text \autocite{A01,B02}.
  \printbiblist[heading=chapterref, segment=\therefsegment]{chapterref}

  \chapter{Second Chapter}
  Some text \autocite{A01,C03}.
  \printbiblist[heading=chapterref, segment=\therefsegment]{chapterref}


  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: chapter 1]
[image: chapter 2]
[image: complete bibliography]

Comment: Great! Can you please add the last name part?

Comment: @pushpen.paul Done!

Comment: OK, solved the `and` problem by putting `\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\addcomma\space}` after `\DeclareBibliographyDriver{chapterref}{` line

Comment: @pushpen.paul Have a look at my edited answer. I prefer `\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\multinamedelim}`, though that is a matter of taste. But you should make sure to include the `%`.

Comment: Why do we need `%`? I thought that was an escape character for comment.

Comment: Only one issue remains. Printing last two digits of year. :-)

Comment: @pushpen.paul The `%` is needed to avoid spurious spaces, see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453/35864). I think it was unlikely that a missing `%` at that position would have caused trouble, but better be safe than sorry and it is a good habit to put `%` where the could be a problem. Have a look at the edit for two-digit years. (Note that the images have not been updated.)

Comment: It doesn't show citation names with `style=trad-alpha` [https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/69706/38244]. Should I post this as a follow-up question?

Comment: @pushpen.paul Yes, please.

Comment: Can you point out the part where you disabled the hyperlink? I'm having a little trouble finding it.

Comment: @hola The code only disables the hyperlink in the chapter bibliographies (`\defbibenvironment{chapterref}`), so that the link that does make it in the end goes to the complete bibliography. The relevant code in `\defbibenvironment{chapterref}` is `\let\blx@anchor\relax`.